# 2046 error when trying to run Macro

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)

DoCmd.GoToControl ("txtVisitorLastName")
SendKeys "-"
Me.Dirty = False
Pause 250

DoCmd.RunMacro ("DeleteCurrentRecord") <--- Error here

Pause 250

DoCmd.Close

DoCmd.OpenForm ("LanguageSelection")

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
```

This is in a VBA within Access 2016 project. Not sure what I can do about it. Any assistance would be great.

Other info about error

It says **Argument 223**

Comment: Apparently a known bug with official workarounds: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244695

Comment: The error is occuring on DoCmd.RunMacro, correct?  For testing, what happens if you comment the error line out, does it open the form LanguageSelection?

Comment: I want to abandon any text in the Textbox so the form is cleared for the next user